# How to remove kanji characters in datetime formatter locale JP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *stringFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSLocale *ja;

if ([[locale localeIdentifier] rangeOfString:@"ja_JP"].location == NSNotFound) {
    ja = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"];
    [stringFormatter setLocale:ja];
}else{
    ja = [NSLocale currentLocale];
}

[stringFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Tokyo"]];
[stringFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
```

Sometimes it return results like this: 20190211午後. I want to keep locale in Japan, but remove 午後 in result. The result should be: 20190211152022.

Comment: Set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX` whenever you want a fixed format like this. Hopefully the result is not something you are showing the user but sending to a server or something similar.

Comment: yes, the result sending to a server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *stringFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    NSLocale *ja;

    if ([[locale localeIdentifier] rangeOfString:@"ja_JP"].location == NSNotFound) {
        ja = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"];
        [stringFormatter setLocale:ja];
    }else{
        ja = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    }

    [stringFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Tokyo"]];
    [stringFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];

    NSString * strdate = [stringFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSLog(@"%@", strdate);
```

It will get like this

```
20181213195829
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Why are you setting the date formatter's locale to `ja_JP` if that isn't the current locale? That's kind of the opposite of the needed solution.